# Dynamically update a TextArea in ASP.Net MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, textarea

I'm a newbie in ASP.net MVC 3. I'm trying to do something trivial, but I spent 1 hour googling for it, to no avail.

I have this view with a TextArea and 2 cascading DropDownLists. The cascading works OK. Now, I'd like to append some text to the text already in the TextArea whenever user makes a new selection in the master dropDownList.

My textAreaFor declaration goes like this:

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.MyText)
```

I set the text to be appended within the ActionResult method that implements the cascading for the slave DDL, like this:

```
public ActionResult Methods(int domain)
{
  model.MyText += "TEST";
  return Json((IEnumerable<CMethod>)model.lstMethodNames[domain], 
    JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I'm obviously missing something here, but I can't figure out what.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

== UPDATE ==

Thanks a lot guys for your answers.

Skuld was right, I should have included my javascript. But it was actually quite similar to the one you posted (although not pure Ajax).

Now, I realize I haven't made myself very clear (soo newbie!). What I'd like to do is update my textarea with additional text initialized *from the controller*, depending on the selection made in the master DDL.

Suppose the master DDL lists continents and the slave DDL lists countries from the selected continent. Depending on the selected continent, I'd like to update my textarea in several possible ways.

And, more broadly, I'd like to be able to add any string that I want to the text in the textarea, like for instance to report results of a business logic operation processed in the background, i.e. not depending on a change of selection in my dropdownlists.

In my ViewModel, I have a

```
[DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
public string Feedback { get; set; }
```

dedicated to that.

I must be missing part(s) of the puzzle, or maybe I'm not yet totally impregnated with the MVC 3 concepts.

Anyway thanks again in advance for your next answers.

Comment: Can you include the javascript code as well, as that is possibly where your issue lies.

Comment: `What I'd like to do is update my textarea with additional text initialized from the controller` Why from the controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Skuld is suggesting, it's likely that there is something wrong in your javascript code.

You should have some javascript like this:

```
//change action for the dropdownlist
$('#ddlSelector').change(function() {
     $.ajax(){
        url: "/controller/action?domain=1", //call to the Methods action
        success: function(){ appendText(); }, // on success call the appendText function
        error: function(){ alert('Error: '+ result.error); } // on failure alert the error
     }
});

//function to append text to the textarea
function appendText(){
   var textArea = $('#selectorTextArea'); //select the textarea to append to
   textArea.val(textArea.val() + " some text to add"); //append text to textarea
}
```